# Поиск k-кратчайших путей в неориентированном графе при помощи алгоритма Йена

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, теория

Не могу найти точных критериев, для каких видов графов справедлив алгоритм Йена, а именно, подходит ли алгоритм для неориентированных взвешенных (все веса ребер > 0) графов?
Вопрос возник из-за реализаций этого алогитма в различных java-библиотеках, в которых ребро графа рассмтривается как ориентированное ребро. А я нуждаюсь в реализации по поиску на неориентированных ребрах.

Comment: http://www.lotos-khv.narod.ru/algoritm/ien.htm
Ответ да. Для неориентированных

Comment: А в англоязычных источниках на ориентированных. Алгоритм должен работать в обоих случаях. Просто для неориентированных считается, что есть пути и туда, и сюда. То есть пишите симметричную матрицу смежности.

Comment: Я в итоге отказался от исследования применимости Йена к неориентированным графам. Использовал алгоритм из core-библиотеки [jgrapht.org], в основе которого лежит алгоритм Беллмана-Форда, который точно работает на неориентированных графах. Всем спасибо за комментарии.